# Regex to check URL

Tags: java, regex, url

I am getting a `redirect` URL in below format.

```
String redirectUrl = "http://beta.test.com/response";
```

And we have to verify this URL against the url stored in our DB,which contains initial of `redirectUrl` like below.

```
String initial = "http://beta.test.com";
```

So for the verification,we do below.

```
if(redirectUri.startsWith(initial)){
   match = true;
}
```

But user can pass below value of `redirectUrl` also.

```
   "http://beta.test.com.attacker.com/response"
   "http://beta.test.com-attacker.com/response"
   "http://beta.test.comattacker/response"
```

All of the above are invalid URL but passes our`startsWith`condition. I can not match it with DB directly.I am looking for some `regex` pattern to check this,but so far unable to implement.

Comment: `String initial = "http://beta.test.com/";`?

Comment: noop, it's only "String initial = http://beta.test.com"; no forward slash at the end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex is still not needed here. You can append a slash in initial URL and call same `starsWith` method:

```
if(redirectUri.startsWith(initial + "/")){
   match = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps help you :

```
(^.*)\/.*$
```

[image]

URL : https://www.regex101.com/